# Hiding object properties from Vue

Tags: vue.js

It is possible to specify certain object properties not to be rendered? This is useful when debugging and masking big objects or objects that form a loop.

For example, if there was an object

```
const a = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

I would only want Vue to display `{a: 1}` not just make `b` unreactive.

Comment: you could set b as a computed property

Comment: Destructure properties from an object(s) and then loop over and show the properties you want to display?

Comment: I was really hoping to modify the object itself but the computed get/setter seems like an option - @DenisTsoi I'd be happy to accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in Vue 2;

The `data` property within the vue component object is where you are given reactivity as a default.

on initialisation: You can set the data model as the following:

**Vue 2**

```
//... vue object
data: {
  a: 1,
  b: null // [1] 
}

// if you call this.b, without setting data you may get an error
```

thereafter, if you wish to only set the property of `b`,
You can set this property with the following computed

```
computed: {
  b: {
    get: function() {
      return this.b
    },
    set: function(newVal) {
      this.b = newVal;
    }
  }
}
```

**Vue3:  Beta**

In Vue 3, [Apr. 2020, subject to change until Vue 3 release] the component initialisation will be replaced with a `setup` method, similar to react hooks, also known as the Composition API.

```
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "component",
  setup() {
    const a = ref(1)
    const updateA = () => {
      a.value++ //
    }

    const b = ref(1)
    const updateB = computed(() => {
      return b // change b
    })

    return {
      a, updateA,
      b
    }
  }
}
```